# in eclipse - cannot run AVD(API-29) CPU/intel x86 getting error -kernel file is missing?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, kernel, qemu

Starting emulator for AVD 'ANDROID10'
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

I am getting this following error during launching  emulator
I am using eclipse , I created emulator using android 10 and API 29 but getting the above error.

kernel qemu isn't present in  folder SDK/system image/x86.one more thing I have also reinstall Intel x86 system image using SDK manager but nothing happens.